# A puzzle about a quote

Tags: quote

A light snack for the evening. Who is the author of the quote at the bottom?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Words:

> Heavy: massive
>  Light: slight
>  tall:  lofty
>  short: petite
>  weird: haunting
>  normal:orderly

Quote:

> Out of all the things I have lost I miss my mind the most

By:

> Mark Twain

Comment: Well done! Saw that quote today and it had me laughing. :)